# NPM Oracle: Inserting BLOBs

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to use the NPM oracle library and update some tables with BLOB values created from files on my computer. Oracle documentation says to use the createLob() function like the following in order to get a value the database will accept:

```
conn.createLob(oracledb.BLOB, function(err, templob) {
if (err) { . . . }
// ... else use templob
});
```

But I have no idea what "use templob" implies...

How do I get my data into these oracledb.BLOB objects?

EDIT: Example of update I am attempting:

```
const queryString = `UPDATE TABLENAME SET BLOB = :blob WHERE ID = 1234;`;
                this.oracleConnection.execute(queryString, 
                    {blob: await fs.readFileSync('/path/to/image.jpg')}
                )
```

Comment: Could you provide some more details about what you're doing? Where do the BLOBs come from (files on the server, web server, etc.)? How large are the BLOBs?

Comment: Files are from my computer as stated. Files are variable size but should all be bellow 1mb for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your use case (small files and limited concurrency), I think the buffer APIs will be the best bet as they are very simple. From [the doc](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-151-simple-insertion-of-lobs):

Given the table:

```
CREATE TABLE mylobs (id NUMBER, c CLOB, b BLOB);
```

an INSERT example is:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var str = fs.readFileSync('example.txt', 'utf8');
. . .

conn.execute(
  `INSERT INTO mylobs (id, myclobcol) VALUES (:idbv, :cbv)`,
  { idbv: 1,
    cbv: str },  // type and direction are optional for IN binds
  function(err, result) {
    if (err)
      console.error(err.message);
    else
      console.log('CLOB inserted from example.txt');
. . .
```

Also, in case you ever need it, I'm wrapping up a mini-series on this topic but it's framed more around web server uploads: https://jsao.io/2019/06/uploading-and-downloading-files-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Comment: This is still giving me an invalid character error on an offset that is inside the buffer. Does it matter that the column I am updating is a BLOB, not a CLOB?

Comment: Updated post with an example

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's a CLOB or BLOB, the driver supports both. Could you please provide the exact error you're getting? Generally, these things are always easier to solve with a reproducible test case. Also, you don't need to await the call to readFileSync since it's a sync method.

Comment: [Error: ORA-00911: invalid character] errorNum: 911, offset: 64

Comment: Note: in my string the 64th offset is the semi-colon

Comment: Ah, with SQL statements, you don't supply the semi-colon at the end. Just remove it and try again.